# How to align controls in WPF custom user controls?

Tags: wpf, controls

So I programmed a WPF custom user control like this:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PEINC.LableWithText"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PEINC"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Beschriftung, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="feld"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

cs:

```
public partial class LableWithText : UserControl
{
    public string Beschriftung
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BeschriftungProperty);
        set => SetValue(BeschriftungProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BeschriftungProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Beschriftung), typeof(string), typeof(LableWithText), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public LableWithText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I use them in solutionDlg.xaml like this:

```
<control:LableWithText Grid.Row="2" Beschriftung="Bezeichnung:"/>
<control:LableWithText Grid.Row="3"  Beschriftung="Projektnummer:"/>
```

My problem is that the TextBoxes don't align. It looks like this:

[image: Looks like this]

But it should look like this:

[image: Should look like this]

It would be cool if the user control would be able to adjust onto a grid - or some other kind of reference line - which is provided by solutionDlg.xaml.

I tried:

- I could work with a fixed Width for the column the label is in. This is my fallback option, but it removes a lot of the flexibility of my custom control + I have to set it for every instance of LableWithText.
- I tried to work with Grid.ColumnSpan, but this didn't work

Comment: Forgive me for asking, by why do you even have this custom control?  It does so little.   Most of its functionality would easily be taken care of simply by manually putting labels into an existing GridView object.  And that would allow you to easily line up the data as you need.  This custom control cannot know about the columns of the control that contains it.

Comment: The example was boiled down so I can ask this question. I removed all the stuff which is not connected to my question so its easier to understand my point.

Comment: You might try to use the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property on the outer, parent `Grid`. Then you could name the columns of the control's grid to match names that you would also give to the columns of the parent `Grid`.  Make the `LabelWithText` control's `ColumnSpan` appropriate  Avoid margins.   Look up `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` for an example.  Let me stress.  I think this a ***bad*** design that will haunt you.  If you can, refactor your control away.  Try to make much of its presentation logic into DataTemplates that could fit into individual columns of a parent Grid View.

Comment: I prefer not to Use "Grids" inside "Grids". gets to be a nightmare sometimes if you are trying to do common alignment and such (like you are). I would switch the `LabelWithText` class to use a `DockPanel` instead of a `Grid` as the container. I would then have the Label use a fixed Width (maybe 200). That way the TextBox would fill. If I am then throwing that in a Grid, use the ColumnSpan to spread it across. If this is possible, I can do an example as an answer.

Comment: @Joe: I looked IsSharedSizeScope up and it seems to work fine. I will think about how Ill implement this exactly. Then Ill post it as an answer. You are welcome to tell me then what exact problems you see with this design. P.S.: I dont see how DataTemplates can help me. They seem to work better with lists while this is about detail-datasets.

Comment: @Ginger Ninja: Why do you think a DockPanal will work better in my user control? The solution with the fixed width would be my fallback option. But it will be hard to find a common width which will fit all my needs.

Comment: @Gener4tor The `DataTemplate`s I envisioned you using would only apply to content within a *single column* of an existing `GridView`.  In other words let the GridView worry about lining up the columns.  Then you just put the individual elements into their individual columns.  i.e. Label in one column and Text in another.  Obviously simple strings do not need `DataTemplate` but other types might.

Comment: @Gener4tor, without knowing all the stuff you striped out and why, so in general, when it comes to adding more complex user controls to a grid layout (anything outside of basic Labels, TextBlock, TextBox, ComboBox, etc.). Layout elements like Padding, Margin, H/V Alignment, etc. are irritating to control in a Grid without some sort of custom style. The Dockpanel handles a lot of alignment for you, and any updates to the inner controls doesnt typically warrant updates to the Grid. So it allows for isolation in layout design. It has improved my efficiency following this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with the SharedSizeGroup-Feature:

This is the xaml I used in my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadBaseGUIElements.LabelWithText"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadBaseGUIElements"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="{Binding LabelSizeGroup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Beschriftung, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Style="{DynamicResource FeldLabel}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="feld" Style="{DynamicResource Feld}" Text="{Binding Inhalt, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is the code I use:

```
public partial class LabelWithText : UserControl
{
    public string Beschriftung
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BeschriftungProperty);
        set => SetValue(BeschriftungProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BeschriftungProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Beschriftung), 
                                                                                                  typeof(string),
                                                                                                  typeof(LabelWithText), 
                                                                                                  new PropertyMetadata("Beschriftung:"));

    public string Inhalt
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(InhaltProperty);
        set => SetValue(InhaltProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InhaltProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Inhalt), 
                                                                                            typeof(string),    
                                                                                            typeof(LabelWithText),
                                                                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                                                                null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string LabelSizeGroup
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(LabelSizeGroupProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelSizeGroupProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelSizeGroupProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LabelSizeGroup), 
                                                                                                    typeof(string),
                                                                                                    typeof(LabelWithText), 
                                                                                                    new PropertyMetadata("Labelspalte"));

    public LabelWithText()
    {
        LabelSizeGroup = "Labelspalte";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

So I can use my User Control like this:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="Labelspalte"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...

    <control:LabelWithText Grid.Row="1" Beschriftung="SVN-Trunk-Pfad:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Inhalt="{Binding SvnTrunkFolder}"/>
</Grid>
```